# How can I set a valid empty date in Moment js?

Tags: angular, angular-material, momentjs, angular7, angular-moment

So, I am using an Angular material datepicker which only helps me select a month and a year.
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#watching-the-views-for-changes-on-selected-years-and-months

However, the functionality doesn't quite work as expected unless you do something like this-
date = new FormControl(moment());
(You are allowed to select the day as well, apart from the month and the year.)

Now moment() as we know just returns the current date and time. My main objective is to display existing user details in a form for an application. However, the user can edit the form after it's loaded. One of those fields is a Material datepicker. Now, it's not a required field, so I don't always receive a valid response from the backend. When the response is a date, there are absolutely no issues. But whenever I receive a null value, that's where the main problem arises.

I had a look at the Moment.js docs (https://momentjs.com/docs/) and it clearly states that moment(null) and moment("") are both invalid dates. And hence once I use either of the two to initialize the datepicker, the datepicker doesn't allow me to select a date in the editable mode at all.

How can I set a valid, empty date using moment() which won't interfere with the datepicker's functionality?

Comment: Can you show the code for the template and the component?

Comment: i'd also like to know the answer to this

Answer (score 9):

We had the same issue in our project and we fixed it by adding a ternary condition for the value of the date picker. `const dateValue = value ? moment(value) : null;` if the value exists we create a moment object from it, if not it should be null.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the `moment` adapter and moment dates, you should set your component's date variable to `null`, and not to `moment(null)`. Internally, the datepicker will ask the adapter if the date is valid but `moment(null).isValid()` returns `false` thus triggering the parse validator that will return an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign undefined to the date like **date = undefined**